# second on campus interview for TT faculty position (3rd interview total)

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

I have a question for anyone who might be a department chair or on a search committee. What does it mean if you get invited for a second on-campus interview? I have already been there once for a standard on campus interview. For context, this is for a tenure track assistant professor position in the sciences.

Comment: Was the first interview on campus?

Comment: An interview invitation doesn't have a hidden meaning.

Comment: no. it is the second on campus interview.

Comment: Oh, the edit makes sense.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer this question, so please go to the interview and tell us what the answer turns out to be.

Comment: Agree with @AnonymousPhysicist, an update to the question regarding what ended up happening might be useful to others who may experience similar things in the future.

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: It's in the US.

Answer (score 6):

I have been a department chair (math department, large US university) and nonetheless find your situation completely baffling. I have literally never heard of a TT job candidate being invited to a second on-campus interview. This is so unusual that I can’t really come up with a plausible guess for why the department that invited you thinks they need you to visit again; moreover, I think this may potentially bring the competence of the people who came up with this plan into question.

Please don’t rely on idle speculation by strangers online. My advice is to email the people who invited you and ask them to clarify what their plan is for the second visit and why they think it is needed. In my opinion, if you already had one on-campus interview, at least in a normal situation they should have all the information about you that they need in order to make a hiring decision. So I’m guessing their explanation may not be the most logical one. But at least you will have a sense of where they’re coming from.

Comment: I agree that this seems unusual.  I have heard of situations where a candidate who has been made a verbal offer is given a chance for a second visit (often with a spouse) to investigate housing, schools, etc., but these visits are after the offer, not before the offer.  If they weren't willing to make an offer after the first interview but are still interested in you then it seems likely that either some important decision maker didn't get to talk to you during the first interview or they have some reservation about hiring you that can only be addressed in interview.

Comment: An example of how this situation could arise: My college requires candidates for tenured (not tenure-track) positions to meet with an associate dean. This policy could be altered at very short notice (actually zero notice) to require the same for tenure-track candidates. In that event, we'd have to re-invite any tenure-track candidate whom we wanted to hire, and that re-visit would have to come before we could make an offer. (I don't say that this is a likely situation, just that it's not entirely absurd.)

Comment: I can imagine that the search committee forwarded two candidates, the dean rejected both (or they both declined the offer) and the search failed; the department then took the remaining candidates to build another short list and for OEO reasons, that requires inviting everyone who is *now* on the short list to be invited to an interview, regardless of whether they had interviewed before. Regardless, it's a rather unusual situation.

Comment: @AndreasBlass in this day and age, the scenario you are describing is completely ridiculous. Such meetings can be done over video. In any case, I don’t find this sort of speculation helpful. We don’t and can’t know what’s going on and OP should simply ask.

Comment: @DanRomik I agree with you about "this day" but not "and age". My university discovered yesterday that what used to be done face-to-face can be done by video (and starting Monday that will apply to all our classes). But until yesterday, meetings between tenure candidates and associate deans had to be in person. Video might have been allowed in extraordinary cases, but "the candidate was already here for an interview" was definitely not extraordinary enough.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I didn’t say it couldn’t happen in this day and age, only that it is ridiculous. Ridiculous things do happen unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you all. Good to hear perspectives from the other side ;).

Answer (score -1):

Generally it would mean that they are very interested, but not absolutely sold. It may be that some senior professor wants to see more of you or meet you for the first time. They may want some student opinion in some places. It isn't frivolous, since they are spending some money, but you still have to close the deal.

In the long term it is probably a good sign that if you get the job they are treating you as a serious contender for eventual tenure. They are doing more than just filling a temporary slot.

But, close the deal.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very helpful answer. Kind of what I thought

Comment: Of course, there may be another candidate in the same situation.